# How do I run script with python-evtx library, from with in the Pycharm terminal?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, logfile

I am running a script that reads information from Windows event log files (evtx). I am using the excellent library from Willi Ballenthin https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx

however, having installed python-evtx, and then imported it into the script as

import Evtx.Evtx as evtx

Pycharm still complaints it can not find it.
I can run the same script from Command or PowerShell, but not from within Pycharm.
I would like to run it from the Pycharm IDE in order to use the IDE features like debugger, watches, and breakpoints.

Python / Pycharm newbie, running Pycharm on a VMWare Windows 10 virtual image, with Python 3.9.3. Any guidance is appreciated and received with gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! To run your script:

1. I would recommend setting up a [virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html?keymap=primary_windows) which you can point the IDE towards in order to help find your installed packages (it helps to keep projects organized & dependency versions under control).

   Current & available interpreters (the executable binary `python`) can be found in the menu on the bottom right of the IDE window, or in settings>Project: (name)>Python Interpreter.
2. In order to execute or debug programs from within PyCharm, you have to set up a ["Run configuration"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html?keymap=primary_windows) for your script/project (these can be found in a drop down menu on the top right).

I hope the docs I linked help you get started, but let me know if you need any further clarification!